# Is it implied that sup and inf are just real numbers? When discussing a subset of $\mathbb Q$, does the sup have to be in $\mathbb Q$ to exist?

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

I need to find the inf, sup, min, max (if they exist) of this set: $\{ x\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}: x<3\}$.
I know that there is no inf or min, since the set is not bounded below. I also know that there is no max, since for any $m$ I can always find some other $x\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$ such that $m<x<3$. I want to say that the sup is 3. What is throwing me off is that $3\notin\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$, and I saw another example talking about a subset of $\mathbb{Q}$ that "didn't have a sup in $\mathbb{Q}$" when it looked like the sup should have been $\sqrt{2}$. So if the question just asks to "find the sup" does that imply I am looking for a sup in all of $\mathbb{R}$ or just in the subset in question?

The other thing that threw me off was that I had to find the inf, sup, min, max (if they exist) of $\{ x\in\mathbb{Q}: x<3\}$ first, and it seemed like I shouldn't get the same answers for both sets.

Comment: Check your definitions.  Typically, $\sup (A)$ is **defined** to be a real number with certain properties, if it exists.  It is not defined as an element of $A$.

Comment: So in the question above, it would be 3, even though it's a rational number? There isn't any definition given - it was one a comprehensive exam sample test, so it is not assumed that all students taking the test had the same class/textbook.

Comment: Yes, the sup of that set is 3, which happens not to belong to the set itself.

Comment: Thank you! So the sets $\{ x\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}: x<3\}$ and $\{ x\in\mathbb{Q}: x<3\}$ have the same inf, min, sup, and max, even though they don't intersect at all.